# How to list all constraints of all tables in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, constraints

How to list all constraints of all tables in PostgreSQL?

I need to search the `unique` constraint created a long time ago, the database has so many (600) tables. It's hard to find. Is there any query to list all `constraints` of all tables

Comment: The easy way is to use `pg_dump --schema-only db_name` and grep the ouput.

Answer (score 2):

You must refer to pg_constraint.

If you need to list just the unique constraint filter on contype, like this:

```
select * from pg_catalog.pg_constraint pc
where contype = 'u'
```

Documentation here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-constraint.html

Answer (score 0):

The below query will List all the constraints of a table in the PostgreSQL database.
You can try below:-

```
SELECT con.*
FROM pg_catalog.pg_constraint con
    INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class rel ON rel.oid = con.conrelid
    INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace nsp ON nsp.oid = connamespace
    WHERE nsp.nspname = '<schema name>'
         AND rel.relname = '<table name>';
```

Replace  with the name of your table &  with the name of your schema.

It can be viewed in PSQL as using below:-

```
d+ <SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME>
```